# Access Key affects the internal style applying for the TextBox

Tags: wpf, xaml

Assume the following xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20" />
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Button Content="Press Me" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />

</Grid>
```

This results as expected in:

[image]

But when I add the '_' sign to button's caption (Content="_Press Me"), it gives me:

[image]

Why?

---------------- **Question update 5 March 2014** ----------------

See my comment to Rohit Vats answer.

Answer (score 1):

If resource is declare without key and only TargetType, that style automatically gets applied to all child controls of that type. So, in your case ***all TextBlocks which falls under visual child collection of Grid will inherit this style automatically***.

---

Now, to answer your question that

> Why setting content to `_PressMe` makes your button to expand by
>   margin of 20 and not in case content is set to `PressMe`.

I hope you are aware of **mnemonics**. I will explain in short, if *text is preceded with underscore sign than first character of Text automatically becomes mnemonic for accessing your button* (Or you can say access key) i.e. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> in your case will act as access key to invoke button click command.

Now that being said **Button's default template** is like this:

```
<ControlTemplate>
   <Border>
      <ContentPresenter RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
   </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

As you can see `ContentPresenter` is responsible for hosting actual Content of your button. ContentPresenter internally host the content inside `AccessText` control which contains `TextBlock` inside its template.

So, in case no mnemonics exist for your button `TextBlock` is never rendered (not sure that how internally it decides, may be switch dataTemplate based on case mnemonics exist or not on templated parent which is button in your case). Hence, margin is not applied and you see button without any Margin set.

But, in case mnemonics exist for button, `TextBlock` gets rendered. And since its a visual child of Grid, it picks default style declared under Resource section. Hence, you see an expanded button with margin 20.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But, actually, I wanted to understand why ContentPresenter *do not* use TextBlock inside when there is no access key set? I digged into ContentPresenter, found templates swithing, then found elements factories... but then code became too complex and dynamic, so I failed with finding the real reason.

Answer (score -1):

The char following '_' becomes accessor key. For example if you want to provide shout-cut for the "Print" button the you can simply type it as *Print, then P will be the short-cut for the button Print. when ever you press on the Key P, click event of print button will get executed. If you don't want that behavior and you want a "*' to appear on the UI the put 2 '*' ('*_').(It'll behave as escape char for strings that we normally use '\')

Press alt key will highlight the Short-cut keys if any for the controls on the UI

Comment: And how does that answer the OP's question?

Comment: That is the WPF controls behavior

Comment: But how does that affect the margin issue? That's OP's question.

Comment: Sorry i wrongly understood the question. Even i saw the behavior it is strange. But if the TargetType is button the behavior is proper.

Comment: Anyhow, downvote is not mine. But yeah this doesn't answer the question.